# Mysql Document WHERE Clause Optimization : Constant expressions used by indexes are evaluated only once

Tags: mysql

Constant expressions used by indexes are evaluated only once.
what does it mean ? Please give an example

Comment: Where my_column = 3*5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any expression that the optimizer can resolve to a constant is resolved to a constant and not evaluated for each row.

```
WHERE start_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

If run today, that query would be exactly equivalent to this one...

```
WHERE start_date >= '2018-04-25'
```

...but not just logically equivalent.  It would be executed *identically* because the expression  `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` can be reduced to a constant, and the optimizer does this when planning the query.

The rows from the index on start_date that are >= '2018-04-25'  would thus be easily found.

The server will *not* extract the start_date from each row, and then evaluate `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` for each row and compare them.